# Unicoin Reputation

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Is the reputation gained from Unicoins permanent? If so, I don't think that's a good idea. People can just essentially buy reputation, skewing the trust ratio.

Not that high rep essentially means you're automagically right, but there is a higher sense of trust from accounts with high reputation. Not to mention it's hard earned.

Or is this just an April Fools joke that went completely over my head? lol..

Comment: Of course it's permanent! For the next six to eight weeks, that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can assure you that it's a 24 hour permanence.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, those were son well earned downvotes on my part. lol

Answer (score 1):

Only the user who buys the powers can see that his reputation has increased. Others will still see the original reputation. I guess this powers will be removed from tomorrow.

Comment: Using unicoins.